# NPM Install running in global route not project directory

Tags: npm, npm-install

I am trying to install the dependancies defined locally in a project folder, so I cd'd into that directory and ran `npm install`, it then tried to find `packages.json` in my user's root folder and threw a load of errors because it couldn't find it. How can I get this to run in the current file path?

> C:\Users\George\Documents\MakeSensePortal\Front-End>npm install
>
> npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
>
> npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
>
> npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\ProgramFiles\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install"
>
> npm ERR! node v4.3.1
>
> npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12
>
> npm ERR! path C:\Users\George\package.json
>
> other errors...
>
> npm ERR! package.json ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\George\package.json'
> npm ERR! package.json This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
> npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.

Comment: is there a package.json inside the Front-End folder?

Comment: @stomo21  yes there is